# What knowledge and equipment do I need to build this device?

Tags: arduino, breadboard, linux, hardware

OK I am a Software Engineer dealing with both low level and C/C++/Java code with a Masters in Software Engineering but no knowledge of Electronic Engineering whatsoever.

I wish to build a device that operates transparently at the IP level and can be inserted into a regular ethernet connection - although not a traffic logging device or a firewall this might be a good example as it is similar to what I wish to accomplish.

So the device looks like this:

Ethernet Connector <-----> Hardware <-------> Ethernet Connector

Hardware lets say analyses at packet level but for the sake of argument does not transform/mutate the packets.

I looked at Arduino type equipment but they have only one ethernet port and just as importantly are the wrong form factor (I wish the device lets say to be tubular to fit in with the cable ergonomics).

Basically I need a sub sized Linux server on a chip preferably self-powered with two ethernet ports.

What books can you recommend to get my up to speed in basic Digital Electronics design as to design such a board? Lets say I have a few months spare to study and learn fast (which I have right now 3 months free between contracts).

Also what hardware do I need to buy to test? A Logic Analyser? Signal Generator? I have no clue really.

I understand the embedded Software side quite though which I hope I an advantage here.

Comment: Do not build your own hardware for this kind of thing if you can at all avoid it. It's expensive and time consuming. Also, self-powered would have to be battery or power-over-ethernet.

Comment: This is not a "basic Digital Electronics design" you're describing. Its very far from being *basic*.

Comment: I was hoping it could be powered by the Ethernet connection (assuming that can generate sufficient power to run an embedded device?)

Comment: Thankyou... I had no idea whether this would be difficult or not.. my only experience was building a 68000 based embedded system back in the 90's but all the design was done.. it didn't seem hugely complicated then.. but then again I was younger and far more naive :)

Comment: If you're operating in passthrough mode, you need all the incoming energy on one side to retransmit on the other, so there is no spare energy to run anything. You might be able to run a very small device if it's passive almost all the time.

Comment: Ethernet does not normally provide power (Ethernet with a PoE injector does, but that's far from standard fare). Maybe you could use a WRT54G router and modify dd-wrt to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: I would think of some well-documented linux-powered router, and then modifying it's firmware..Update: Ok, I'm late. @SpehroPefhany has it already..

Comment: I am quite familiar with the WRT54G and dd-wrt unfortunately the device itself is just too large and bulky for my needs. I did try custom dd-wrt builds to achieve my aims but they turned out to be flaky. As this would be a  simple 'turnkey' device without the excessive bulk I had to abandon that strategy early on unfortunately. Great advice though.

Comment: If you are thinking of some kind of commercial product, the development might start like this, and then you could think of building custom hardware by cloning relevant parts of that router. Well, probably using DD-WRT for commercial product is illegal, but for development..why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy an ethernet hub with 3 or more ports. Can be a bit hard to find, there are sometimes people selling Netgear hubs on Ebay really cheap. Check the photographs of the hub and make sure it says hub on it and NOT switch. A lot of people and companies use the word interchangeably and even together on the graphics branding on the product.

The hub will relay packets between the input and output ethernet connectors in your 'diagram'. Take the third port on the hub and connect to the ethernet port on the arduino. Job done except for writing a bit of code.

The Arduino can then see all the traffic passing between the two ethernet ports you're interested in.

This will reduce the amount of software you have to write, you don't have to worry about writing software to transport the packets between the two ethernet ports, all you have to do is write the software to read packets on the Arduino and analyse them.

But note the Arduino can't modify the data packets passing between the two ethernet ports, but that's what you want, the data to pass transparently and unmodified between them.

Comment: An Arduino does not begin to have the memory or I/O bandwidth for a such a job.  Really the only reason you can hang one off Ethernet via a proxy is that when the Arduino is the target of communication, the other end has to confine itself to the pace at which the Arduino becomes ready; that doesn't hold for snooping.